# google crawler and news ticker

Tags: jquery, web-crawler, google-search-console

I am using a jQuery News Ticker on my site. Since I am concerned with SEO mainly, I want to know if google crawler will consider the constantly updated news ticker headlines  as new content or not? or am I better off having a news section on the site?

This is the newsticker I am using: www.jquerynewsticker.com/

regards,

Answer (score 0):

Can we see your site? Without further infos i would believe that a newsticker which only provides snippets and a link to the original is not counted as duplicate content.

And i don t believe that Google will index your snippet from the ticker. maybe you can work with noindex or something, but i have rather no idea how you integrated this code in your website.